# Unable to hide a certain div when click outside of it

Tags: jquery

I'v searching for a way to hide a toggling div which is already hidden by default. I want to hide the div if user click outside of it!

I tried this:

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $("#tab").hide();
     $("#open_tab").on("click",function(){
        $("#tab").toggle();    
        $("*").on("mouseup",function(e){
              var clicked=$(this).attr("id");
              if(clicked !="tab"){
                 e.stopPropagation();
                 $("#tab").hide();
              }
             else {
                   e.stopPropagation();
             }
        });
     });
}); </script>
```

But i don't know what's wrong with my code. Please can anyone help?

Comment: your code worked when I tried it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mNyS/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The `toggle()` jQuery function:

> Display or hide the matched elements. ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/))

So, you don't need any `mouseup` event. Just use `toggle()` function `on click` for `#open_tab`.

### HTML

```
<div id="open_tab">Click</div>
<div id="tab">TOGGLE</div>
```

### Javascript

```
$("#tab").hide();
$("#open_tab").on("click", function () {
    $("#tab").toggle();
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RxynW/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `mouseup` event gets registered only on `click` event on `open_tab`.  You should move 
this block outside of `$("#open_tab").on("click",function()`.  Please try the following:

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $("#tab").hide();
     $("#open_tab").on("click",function(){
        $("#tab").toggle();    
     });

     $("*").on("mouseup",function(e){
          var clicked=$(this).attr("id");
          if(clicked !="tab"){
              e.stopPropagation();
              $("#tab").hide();
          } else {
              e.stopPropagation();
          }
     });
}); 
</script>
```

**Update:** Here is a shorter version for you:

```
<script>
    $("#tab").hide();
    $(document).on('click', function (evt) {
        if (evt.target.id == 'open_tab') {
            $('#tab').toggle();
        } else if (evt.target.id != 'tab') {
            $('#tab').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I did it that way to only trigger when `#open_tab` is click so it would'nt affect other `click` events. Is there any way to do this only when `#opent_tab` is clicked?

Comment: @StanleyAmos, please see my updated script.